# Photodiode draws current from op-amp input

Tags: operational-amplifier, photodiode

I am trying to measure light intensity using a photodiode (S1336-18BQ) connected to an op-amp (LF412CP) in transimpedance amplifier configuration. I couldn't get it to work correctly, so I started searching for problems and have found something very peculiar: there is a current flowing from the negative input of the op-amp. The value of the current is the same order of magnitude as the short-circuit current of the photodiode under the same conditions (~1 µA).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi7Hvn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have very little experience in analog electronics, but I understand that inputs of an op-amp (especially a JFET one) should have very high impedance. I have tried three identical op-amps to ensure that it is not just a damaged chip. Please forgive me if I am asking something obvious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

The op-amp you have chosen (LF412) is unsuitable for the power supply regime you show in your schematic. The input common-mode voltage range is a couple of volts inside the power rails hence putting the non-inverting input to ground (also your negative supply rail) is a mistake - you need bipolar supplies for this op-amp.

In addition, the minimum supply recommended for this op-amp is +/- 5 volts (a span of 10 volts) and you are showing it on a single 5 volt rail: -

[image]

This op-amp won't work properly on a single 5 volt rail.

Answer (score 4):

It does not work with single 5V supply.

Datasheet says minimum supply voltage for LF412CP is +/- 3.5V

The circuit is also exceeding the common mode input voltage range. It does not go down to negative supply voltage.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want a single-supplied circuit, try this clever H&H circuit solution (Page 253, Fig. J):

[image: AE Photodiode converter]

I have explained it in [my answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/473488/61398) to a similar question two years ago. The role of the second resistor R2 is to "lift" the voltage drop across the "floating" photodiode above the ground thus ensuring a kind of a "self-biasing".

I have illustrated the circuit operation by means of voltage bars (in red) and current loops (in green). Looking at the picture now I think the voltage across the photodiode should have an opposite polarity.

Comment: Worth noting they'll still need more than 5 V as the supply, as well, unless they use a different op-amp.

Comment: @Hearth, True... but the op-amp is single supplied...

Comment: That doesn't change that it still needs a minimum of 7 V across its power terminals to work.

Comment: @Hearth, Of course...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I ended up using a 12 V power supply and LDO set at 6 V for the non-inverting input. This way I can variate the feedback resistor value without worrying that a large value will lead to the inputs being “too close” to 0 V.